# How do I change a div's border color if the input field contained with it is not empty?

Tags: html, css, forms, parent-child

I'm creating a form using only html and css. I want each question on the form to have a visual aid by giving it's containing div a red border-left color that changes to green if the input field is filled in.

This is my html:

```
<div class="form-unit">
  <label for="name" id="name-label"><b>Name</b></label>
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Please enter your full name" required>
</div>
```

And this is the relevant css:

```
.form-unit {
  margin: 40px 0;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-left: 3px solid rgb(200, 80, 100);
}
```

I want to change the color of the div's border like so:

```
.form-unit:??? {
  border-left: 3px solid rgb(160, 200, 80);
}
```

What is the syntax to target the div when the `input[type="text"]` is not empty? Is it at all possible with just html and css?

Comment: There is no way to target the div as its a prent element, and CSS does not provide an ancestor selector (this would hugely complicate CSS). So its not directly possible. Can I also advice you it might be better to replace the `div ` with the `label` as a wrapper? Then your inputs dont need IDs, and your labels don't need `for`, and you inherit some possibilites with the `label` element I think. Just a suggestion. But what you want is not possible in pure CSS.

Comment: doubt it until `has()` is implemented in CSS

Answer (score 0):

there is no [parent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) yet, you have to think it otherwise :

you could use a sibbling selector with an empty tag

```css
.form-unit {
  margin: 40px 0;
  padding-left: 15px;
  position: relative;
  border-left: 3px solid rgb(160, 200, 80);
}

input:invalid+b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -3px;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 3px solid rgb(200, 80, 100);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-unit">
  <label for="name" id="name-label"><b>Name</b></label>
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Please enter your full name" required>
  <b></b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort of do what you're looking for using the `valid` pseudo command in CSS.  You can have the box highlight if there's text inside.  Take a look at this:

```css
input {
  font: inherit;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  border: 0.125em solid rgb(200, 80, 100); 
  outline: none;
}

input:valid{
  border-color: rgb(160, 200, 80);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-unit">
  <label for="name" id="name-label"><b>Name</b></label>
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Please enter your full name" required>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

And just for fun, you can add a checkmark or and X after the box. like this:

```css
input {
  font: inherit;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  border: 0.125em solid rgb(200, 80, 100); 
  outline: none;
}

input:valid{
  border-color: rgb(160, 200, 80);
}

input:invalid + span::before {
  content: '✖';
  color: red;
}

input:valid + span::before {
  content: '✓';
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-unit">

  <label for="name" id="name-label"><b>Name</b></label>

  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Please enter your full name" required>
      <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this using the a `span` along with a `valid` psuedo command. Check it out!

```css
input:invalid + span::before {
  content: '';
  margin: 40px 0;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-left: 3px solid rgb(200, 80, 100);
}

input:valid + span::before {
  content: '';
  margin: 40px 0;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-left: 3px solid rgb(160, 200, 80);
}

span {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-unit">

  <label for="name" id="name-label"><b>Name</b></label>

  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Please enter your full name" required>
      <span></span>
</div>
```